# Additional hrule in halign after page break

Tags: page-breaking, tex-core, rules, plain-tex

I try to spread a halign over more than one page. I use `\filbreak` after every line.

```
\tracingonline=1
\advance\vsize by -15cm
\def\tablerule{\noalign{\hrule height .3mm\filbreak}}
\newcount\posno\posno=1
\def\pos{\hskip3pt\number\posno\global\advance\posno by 1}
\tabskip=0pt%
\halign to 400pt{\vrule width 0pt height 12pt depth 6pt#\tabskip=1em&#\tabskip=1em&#\tabskip=1em plus 1fil&#\tabskip=1em\cr
  \tablerule%
  \hskip3pt%
  {\bf Pos.} & {\bf Anz.} & {\bf Beschreibung} & {\bf Seriennummer}\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
  \pos & 1 St. & Abcdefg & 123/12/12-1234567\cr\tablerule
}
\bye
```

The problem is: when a page break happens an `\hrule` is missing at the top of the new page.

[image: example]

Is is possible to check if `\filbreak` has created a page break in order to add an additional `\hrule` for the new page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't *detect* that because at the time TeX does page-breaking it has long finished expanding macros. However you can trick it into inserting a rule there for you.

If you change your `\tablerule` to:

```
\def\tablerule{\noalign{%
  \hrule height .3mm
  \filbreak\vskip-.3mm
  \hrule height .3mm}}
```

then each rule will be doubled, but due to the negative `\vskip` they will overlap, so only one will be visible. However at a page break the rules will be separated across pages due to the `\filbreak`, and the `\vskip` will be discarded at the top of the next page, and you will have the two rules you want.

This is (an oversimplified version of) what `longtable` does when it finds an `\hline`, except that `longtable` generalises for the case of different rule widths and a possible double `\hline`.

> [image]

Comment: brilliant idea, I wonder if latex has a package that does that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `colortbl`, of course :-)